# WPF: ScrollViewer with more than one DataGrid and Label

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scroll, scrollviewer

In my WPF-Application I have a window which contains many dynamic DataGrid with a Label on top as the heading line. These Elements are children of an ScrollViewer. 
If I scroll up or down the ScrollViewer always jump to the Label. From the Content of the DataGrids only the first columns are visible.
My WPF-Code:

```
<ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True" PanningMode="VerticalFirst" MouseWheel="ResultDataGrid_OnMouseWheel" x:Name="ResultScrollViewer" Height="Auto">
  <StackPanel x:Name="ResultStackPanel">
  <TextBlock Text="Result" Style="{StaticResource Heading2}" />
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ResultStackPanel}">
       <Label Content="Informations" x:Name="LabelInfo" Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}"/>
       <DataGrid x:Name="ResultMeta" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ResultStackPanel}">
       <Label Content="Statistics" Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}"/>
       <DataGrid x:Name="ResultStat" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource ResultStackPanel}">
       <Label Content="Resources" Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" />
       <DataGrid x:Name="ResultResources" Style="{StaticResource DataGridStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
    <!-- ... -->
  </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default scroll behavior of a `ScrollViewer` is scrolling elements.
You can try to change this behavior to set this to pixel with the option `CanContentScroll="bool"`.

More information can you get from the MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll(v=vs.110).aspx

But remember that this option will force the `ScrollViewer` to load all available elements and not the elements that are shown (performance on loading).

Comment: This property changed nothing. I expect that this is a dependency of each DataGrid height. If I scroll down, the height of the scrollbar is changed.

Comment: Have you tried to change the child `StackPanel` with name "ResultStackPanel" with a Grid and defined `Grid.Rows`with Value `Auto` and the last Row with `*` value?

Comment: Great! Please accept this as an answer if it resolves your query.